# ActionLink and asp-action not working inside a row table body when code is use in Partialview o ComponentView Asp.net core 2.2

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

The code works fine in Asp.net MVC in partialViews   but in Asp.net core 2.2 only works directly in Views,   @Html.ActionLink and asp-action are like disabled, when I use it inside table row

this is the code:

If a remove table tag, action links are enabled again.

```
<table class="table clsTableColorGreen">
@foreach (var item in Model.Detalle)
{
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmpresaProducto.CnProdDesc)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CnCantidad)
        </td>

        <td>
            <a asp-action="DeleteItem" asp-area="Facturacion" asp-controller="Facturas" asp-route-id="@item.CnFacturaDetalleID">Eliminar</a>
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Eliminar", "DeleteItem", new { id = item.CnFacturaDetalleID }, new { @class = "btn btn-link glyphicon glyphicon-remove", @id = "btnEliminarItem" })
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="delete-section">
                <a class="delete-link glyphicon glyphicon-remove" href="@Url.Action("DeleteItem2", new {id = item.CnFacturaDetalleID}  )">Eliminar</a>
                <div class="btn btn-primary delete-confirm" style="display:none" data-delete-id="@item.CnFacturaDetalleID ">Confirmar Eliminar</div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

i expect to show a link in every row an be able to click it, when the code is inside of partiaview or component view

***** Uptated  Resolve ****** 
I think the problem could for the change of Bootstrap from 3.X to for Bootstrap v4.3.1 when i migrate to a asp.net core.

i resolve the problem in the bootstrap datatable just changing the position of de links from the last column to the first column, an everythings work fine.
thank you friends.

```
        <table class="table clsTableColorGreen">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        #
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Detalle[0].CnProdID) // All headers
                    </th>


                    <th></th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model.Detalle)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>  // change tp first line 
                            <div class="delete-section">
                                <a class="delete-link glyphicon glyphicon-remove" href="@Url.Action("DeleteItem2", new {id = item.CnFacturaDetalleID}  )">Eliminar</a>
                                <div class="btn btn-primary delete-confirm" style="display:none" data-delete-id="@item.CnFacturaDetalleID ">Confirmar Eliminar</div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmpresaProducto.CnProdDesc) // all content
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                }

        </table>
```

Comment: What is your specific for "@Html.ActionLink and asp-action are like disabled" ? I made a test but it worked , I assume that if you add " @addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers " in _ViewImports.cshtml .Could you share a sample demo that can reproduce your issue ?

Comment: all my tags links were ok, i think the problem is something in bootstrap version.